# WinAPI: Image on hover

Tags: winapi, gdi+

A friend of mine is about to release an application and asked me to create a launcher for it. I found it a good excuse to finally study WinAPI and thought that a simple launcher would be easily doable even in a relatively small time window.

I was wrong.

I'm trying to create a launcher window with 5 buttons that start different things. The goal is to have transparent buttons (not done yet) that have a smaller image inside them. The image should only be displayed when the user hovers over the larger button area.

The images are in .png format. I'm using GDI+ and loading PNG files from resources with http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3537/Loading-JPG-PNG-resources-using-GDI.

I'm using MouseTrackEvents to keep track of the mouse and I've also subclassed a button. The problem is that I don't know how I should handle the WM_MOUSELEAVE message. I don't know how to erase the image I've drawn. If I have to save the ht_img as a variable and refer to it later, I don't know how.

Here's what I have so far. This example loads the .png from resource IDB_Website2. Displaying the image works (although it keeps being rendered over and over again currently):

WndProc:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
int wmId, wmEvent;
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC hdc;
GDI gdi;

switch (Msg)
{
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        HWND hwndButton = CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), NULL,
                          WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
                          80, 10, 100, 50,
                          hWnd, (HMENU) HT_BUTTON1, NULL, NULL);
        HTButton = (WNDPROC) SetWindowLong(hwndButton, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG) ButtonProc);
    }
...

    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        gdi.InitList(hInst, hdc);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
```

Buttonproc (subclassed button):

```
LRESULT CALLBACK ButtonProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
MouseTrackEvents MouseTrack;
GDI gdi;

HDC odc = GetDC(GetParent(hWnd));

switch(Msg)
{
    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        MouseTrack.OnMouseMove(hWnd);
        break;

    case WM_MOUSEHOVER:
        gdi.Create(IDB_Website2, _T("PNG"), hInst, odc, 62, 347, 200, 40, true);
        MouseTrack.Reset(hWnd);
        break;

    case WM_MOUSELEAVE:
        MouseTrack.Reset(hWnd);
        break;
}

return CallWindowProc (HTButton, hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

class GDI's Create graphic method:

```
void Create(UINT menuid, LPCTSTR pType, HMODULE hInst, HDC hdc, int x, int y, int w, int h)
{
    Graphics grpx(hdc);

    ht_img = new CGdiPlusBitmapResource();
    ht_img -> Load(menuid, pType, hInst);
    grpx.DrawImage(*ht_img, x, y, w, h);
    delete ht_img;
}
```

This has been quite a challenge so far! It's been fun although a bit tear-my-hair-out inducing at times. :-) I'd be grateful for any advice on how I should proceed.

---

EDIT: Answering Adrian

I tried changing my Buttonproc, but the image doesn't seem to be rendered. Here's what I did:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK ButtonProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    MouseTrackEvents MouseTrack;
    GDI gdi;
    HDC odc = GetDC(GetParent(hWnd));
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;

    int result;

    switch(Msg)
    {
    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        MouseTrack.OnMouseMove(hWnd);
        break;

    case WM_MOUSEHOVER:
        hovering = true;
        break;

    case WM_MOUSELEAVE:
        hovering = false;
        MouseTrack.Reset(hWnd);
        break;

    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        result = CallWindowProc(HTButton, hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
        if (hovering == true) {
            gdi.Create(IDB_Play2, _T("PNG"), hInst, hdc, 62, 100, 200, 40);
        }
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        return result;
    }
    return CallWindowProc (HTButton, hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want to do the painting directly in the handling of the mouse events.  You probably want to handle WM_PAINT in the button proc by calling the underlying implementation and then augmenting it based on the hover state.  Then your mouse handling corresponds to flipping a state variable and invalidating the button (which will cause it to repaint).

```
case WM_PAINT:
    // start with the standard rendering
    int result = CallWindowProc (HTButton, hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
    // then overdraw our embellishments
    if (my_state_variable == hovering) {
         DrawOverlayImage();
    }
    return result;  // don't just break here, or you'll call CallWindowProc again
```

Comment: I'm having difficulties understanding the "You probably want to handle WM_PAINT in the button proc by calling the underlying implementation and then augmenting it based on the hover state." part. How would I go about calling the underlying implementation?

Comment: I tried your advice but couldn't get it working. :( I probably misunderstood something... Please see the edit I made to my question. Also, DrawOverLayImage() doesn't seem familiar...?

Comment: You also need to call InvalidateRect for the button windows when the state changes.  That'll trigger the repaint.  DrawOverlayImage was just my pseudocode shorthand for whatever drawing mechanism you choose to use.

Comment: I was obviously missing the BeginPaint and EndPaint commands, and now after adding them, the button is removed completely. Guess I need to read more about subclassing buttons, heh.

Comment: Calling InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, true); on WM_MOUSEHOVER didn't do anything. I guess BeginPaint & EndPaint studying it is?

Comment: The WM_PAINT loop works in the sense that if I stick a PostQuitMessage(0); in it, it breaks on hover... but I can't get the new graphic to display. Vexing.

Comment: Regardless! I got your suggestion to work - now the hover-detection and image-rendering works great. I'm moving on to hiding the default button background now. Thanks!